# Close post request connection when node js error occurs

Tags: javascript

colleagues, please tell me how do I handle the error so that I can return the result to postman. When the postman behavior occurs infinite loading

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import { sendEmail } from "../../mailsend/SendMail";
// будт приходить с клиента три массива [connectionData: {from, pass}] [sendMail: {to}] [dataText: {subject, text}]

const routerMailSend = express.Router();

routerMailSend.post("/", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    return res.status(400).send("Missing from property in request body");
  }
  console.log(req.body);

  const { connectionData, dataText, sendMail } = req.body //В таком виде будут приходить с клиента массивы
//   const { from, pass, to, subject, text } = req.body;
  try{
    const promises = sendMail.map(async (recipient: string) => {
        const {from, pass} = connectionData[Math.floor(Math.random() * connectionData.length)];
        const {subject, text} = dataText[Math.floor(Math.random() * dataText.length)];
        console.log(from, pass);
        
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout( async () => {
              try {
                  const transfer = await sendEmail(from, pass, recipient, subject, text);
                  console.log("message send process");
                  resolve(transfer);
              } catch (err) {
                  console.log("Connect refused");
                  reject(new Error("Incorrect login or password"))        ----------Close the post request connection if an error occurs at this location and return the response to postman          
              }
            }, Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000 - 3000 + 1) + 3000))
        })
      })

      const results = await Promise.all(promises);
      res.status(200);

      return res.json({ message: "Message send access" });
  } catch (err) {
      res.status(400);
      return ({ message: "Message send error" });
  }
});

export default routerMailSend;
```

I tried to return different res.json data

Comment: is no error thrown? Maybe just to be sure you can add a `console.error(err)` to the `catch` block.

Comment: the error returns, but the post request is still waiting for a response

Answer (score 0):

the question was solved in this way
I changed for to while and instead of wrapping it in settimeout I created a promise and set a random execution time

```js
routerMailSend.post("/", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    return res.status(400).send("Missing from property in request body");
  }
  console.log(req.body);

  const { connectionData, dataText, sendMail } = req.body; //В таком виде будут приходить с клиента массивы
  //   const { from, pass, to, subject, text } = req.body;
  try {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < sendMail.length) {
      const recipient = sendMail[i];
      const { from, pass } = connectionData[Math.floor(Math.random() * connectionData.length)];
      const { subject, text } = dataText[Math.floor(Math.random() * dataText.length)];
      console.log(from, pass);

      try {
        const transfer = await sendEmail(from, pass, recipient, subject, text);
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000 - 3000 + 1) + 3000)));
        console.log("message send process");
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.json("Incorrect login or password");
      }

      i++;
    }

    res.status(200);
    return res.json({ message: "Message send access" });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400);
    return { message: "Message send error" };
  }
});
```